# sklearn LinearRegression predict returns different results for full dataframe vs iteration over rows

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

My model class uses StandardScaler and Linear Regression

```
def train(self, data):
    features = data[self.feature_names].values
    target = data[self.target_name].values

    self.scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaled_features = self.scaler.fit_transform(features)

    self.regressor = LinearRegression()
    self.regressor.fit(scaled_features, target)
```

Now I have defined two functions which should either handle a single entry (pandas Series) or multiple entries (pandas DataFrame)

```
def predict_one(self, single_data):
    """
    returns a float
    """
    features = single_data[self.feature_names].values.reshape(1, -1)
    scaled_features = self.scaler.transform(features)
    return self.regressor.predict(scaled_features)[0,0]

def predict_many(self, multi_data):
    """
    returns a 1D numpy array of floats
    """
    features = multi_data[self.feature_names].values
    scaled_features = self.scaler.transform(features)
    return self.regressor.predict(scaled_features).flatten()
```

Then I check whether if I iterate through `.iterrows()` and save `predict_one()` results in a list, I get the same results as for `predict_many()`.

And I don't.

I have now followed the rabbit hole - it is not the StandardScaler, rather if I just call self.regressor either on full dataset or row by row I get slightly different results:

```
array([[3.10862447e-15],
       [3.10862447e-15],
       [3.10862447e-15],
       [3.10862447e-15] ...

vs 

[array([[3.55271368e-15]]),
 array([[3.55271368e-15]]),
 array([[3.55271368e-15]]),
 array([[3.55271368e-15]]),
```

I just wonder why, even if it is E-15 scale.

Comment: Check if the `features` variable passed in `predict_one` has correct shape and data. @Alex